# "Segmentation fault: 11" in Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, swift, closures, swift3

Is it really forbidden to use `if...let` inside closures in **Swift 3**? Xcode constantly gives me `Swift Compiler Error / Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11` when I put it in a closure.

```
import Foundation

class ItemsManager: NSObject {

    fileprivate let networking: Networking

    init(networking: Networking) {
        self.networking = networking
    }

    func fetchItems() {
        networking.fetchItemsSuccess({ [weak self] (responseObject: Any) in

            // the line below causes "Segmentation fault: 11"
            if let itemDictionaries = responseObject as [Dictionary] {
                // ...
            }
            // ...                    
        }, failure: { [weak self] in
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

While the current class is in swift, `Networking` is written in **Objective-C**, where `responseObject` is declared as `id`. Swift treats it as `Any`.

**UPDATE 2**

I checked a type of the `responseObject` in runtime, it appears to be `__NSArrayI`. Is it normal?

Comment: What is the type of `responseObject`? Maybe you should be using `as?`?

Comment: This is a very good question, I'll update my question to depict it.

Comment: Is that Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: @HAS it's Swift 3.

Comment: Then try `as? Dictionary` instead.

Comment: @HAS unfortunately, it ends up with the same error. (I also restarted Xcode to be sure the error is not cached.)

Comment: Delete derived data, try again (close xcode, cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, rm -rf *, restart xcode).

Comment: @i_am_jorf doesn't help.

Comment: try as? [String: AnyObject] and remove the : Any because it is inferred.

Comment: @Sethmr works! If you post an explanation in a form of an answer, I'll accept. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

class ItemsManager: NSObject {

    fileprivate let networking: Networking

    init(networking: Networking) {
        self.networking = networking
    }

    func fetchItems() {
        networking.fetchItemsSuccess({ [weak self] responseObject in

            if let itemDictionaries = responseObject as [[String: AnyObject]] {
                // ...
            }

        }) { [weak self] in
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I would write this function. (I like using trailing closures like what I did.)

The type of what is returned is inferred from the function definition so placing anything there might just confuse the compiler. Removing extraneous details became a big thing in **Swift 3**, so that could be your error.

The next thing is that `Dictionary` is a `[String: AnyObject]` by nature. There are ways of type defining a `Dictionary` using the word `Dictionary`, but why bother when we can define it directly.